# Why does "turtle.pd" produce a syntax error in my Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was trying to make a sort-of complex parametric grapher, but that isn't what's important. What's important is that my program is supposed to draw a circle using Turtle graphics, and when I put the pen down, I have a syntax error in the "`turtle.pd()`" line. I have no idea what's going on. Can you guys help me? My program is below.

```
import turtle, math, cmath
def f(x): return math.e ** (1j * x) # Use Python code to define f(x) as the return value; don't forget the math and cmath modules are imported
precision = 25 # This program will draw points every (1 / precision) units
def draw(x):
    value = f(x)
    try:
        turtle.xcor = value.real * 25 + 100
        turtle.ycor = value.imag * 25 + 100
    turtle.pd() # Syntax error here
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.pu()
draw(0)
num = 0
while True:
    num += 1
    draw(num)
    draw(-num)
```

Comment: `try` needs an `except`. In general, if you get a `SyntaxError` somewhere unexpected, look at the previous line / block to see if you forgot to close something, e.g. a `)` or, as in this case, an `except`.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem

Comment: "Doesn't solve the problem" isn't a helpful response. Please read [ask]. What _exact_ change did you make to the code?

Comment: Why is the `try` there in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the missing `except` clause syntax error that @dguis points out (+1), I wonder what you think these lines are doing:

```
turtle.xcor = value.real * 25 + 100
turtle.ycor = value.imag * 25 + 100
```

If `.xcor` and `.ycor` are your own properties that you've stashed on a turtle instance, then it's OK.  If you think this moves the turtle -- then not.  If the goal is to move the turtle, try:

```
turtle.setx(value.real * 25 + 100)
turtle.sety(value.imag * 25 + 100)
```

Complete solution with additional tweaks:

```
import turtle
import math

def f(x):
    return math.e ** complex(0, x)

def draw(x):
    value = f(x) * 25

    turtle.setx(value.real + 100)
    turtle.sety(value.imag + 100)

    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.penup()

turtle.penup()

num = 0

draw(num)

while True:
    num += 1
    draw(num)
    draw(-num)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add

```
except [errortype]:
    pass
```

after the `try` block. Replace [errortype] with the error that you hoped to reduce with the try block. I don't see what error could be raised within that block, to you could likely just write

```
turtle.xcor = value.real * 25 + 100
turtle.ycor = value.imag * 25 + 100
```

and remove the try block all together.

Comment: Why would you just `pass` in the `except` block? Why is the `try` even there? You can't recommend a good exception handling strategy without understanding the context and knowing what you're trying to protect against.

Comment: Yes, that is why I also recommended that they could remove the try-except block all together. I understand it is silly to pass in the except block, but @WilliamPowell could then change `pass` to anything else they want.